# PrintInvoice global variable - BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I have the following case:

I'm trying to edit the PrintInvoice.html after downloading it through WebDav. The template was previously edited by another developer, but using the Template Files directly in the Storefront back when the files were visible in the Storefront. When opening the HTML template, the wording that I need to change is inside the global variable %%GLOBAL_ProductsTable%% so I'm not sure how to reach the text content inside. Replacing the global variable with custom HTML is not desirable.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, these global variables are saved within BC's back-end database which you do not have access to.

A workaround my team and I have done to edit the contents of these global variables is to use JavaScript at the bottom of the document that changes the desired text after it is loaded. This seems to be the only way we could find to edit those values.

Comment: So far that's the only solution unless editing the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables like this are provided by the BigCommerce app, it is how the product data is sent through your store to email and can't be modified. To change the product table's appearance, the existing variable would need to be removed and replaced with your custom code.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this solution. I saw someone discussing AJAX call solution, but not in-depth in order for me to get more information on the matter.